# Which Honda cars are equipped with permanent AWD?

Tags: honda, 4wd, awd

I am not looking for RT-AWD cars with automatic AWD which are usually FWD but permanent AWD cars.

Comment: Hoping to clarify ... you are looking for Honda vehicles which are full-time AWD?

Comment: Yes, 4WD which is enabled at all times, not just under certain conditions.

Comment: I think you are mincing items here. There is a difference between 4WD and AWD. 4WD meaning it is selectable from the driver's seat from 2WD to 4WD, usually with a high/low range as well. AWD usually means the vehicle stays in 4WD at all times and is not driver selectable (also does not have high/low range transfer case). AWD does not mean all four wheels are engaged at all times, though. The other two wheels will only be engaged when there is slippage detected in the main drive wheels. If this is your understanding, I can answer your question.

Comment: I'm looking for full-time AWD then.

Comment: How far into the "legacy" models do you want to look? All the way back to the first Honda car ever built, or just current models? New models only, or models available within the last X years?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that could quickly become obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the CR-V, Pilot, Ridgeline, and Crosstour with the AWD option. Understand that these vehicles will not engage all four wheels at all times. If you are looking for a vehicle where all four wheels are engaged all of the time, I don't think you'll find one, whether it's a Honda or not. 4WD/AWD vehicles are designed with a bias built into the transfer case which puts ~60% of the power to the main drive wheels and the rest to the alternate wheels. The alternate wheels do not engage until the mains start to slip. This is called a torsion bias.

Comment: Subaru's symmetrical AWD is a full-time AWD platform. Power is always sent to all 4 wheels unless slippage is detected, which at that point it will redirect power to the wheels with more grip. [Source](http://www.subaru.com/engineering/all-wheel-drive.html). "Symmetrical All-Wheel Drive sends power to all wheels simultaneously for maximum traction and acceleration.

In slippery conditions, that power is actively distributed to the wheels with the best traction."

Comment: @ellesedil ... And you would be correct. I'm surprised Bob Cross didn't say something. He's a big Subie guy. Thanks for squaring me away :-)

Comment: Actually the reason I ask is because I am aware of civic with both realtime-awd (which gets enabled when the front wheels loose grip as well as a civic which was available in germany with all time awd

Comment: Land Rover Defenders are symmetrical AWD as well, along with older Range Rovers and Discoveries, using conventional mechanical differentials to distribute power. I had assumed other 'proper' 4x4s (Hilux etc) were as well, but I may well be wrong...

Comment: @Ellesedil, Subarus also have the additional plus of being totally awesome.  There, I said it.

Comment: Good point on the "all four wheels". The Honda VTM-4 system can and does clutch-in both rear wheels at the same time, but only one of the two front wheels will spin at a time in a slippery situation. (Three out of four isn't bad!) When not engaged, it acts like a normal FWD (Front Wheel Drive) vehicle.

Answer (score 2):

Honda's Super Handling All Wheel Drive ([SH-AWD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SH-AWD)) [is a full-time 4WD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuUaqFnsb2M) system, available on [Honda Legend](http://www.awdwiki.com/en/honda/#Legend_2004____) and Honda's luxury brand Acura (models RL, MDX, RDX, TL, ZDX).

Cars equipped with Variable Torque Management 4WD ([VTM-4](http://www.ridgelineownersclub.com/Variable-Torque-Management-VTM-4-Explanation)) fall somewhere in between. While normally FWD, they engage rear wheels on any acceleration and allow driver to lock all-wheel drive on low speeds and gears. VTM-4 has been used on [Honda Pilot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_Pilot#Off-road_capability) and [Honda Ridgeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_Ridgeline#Honda.27s_AWD_traction_system).